# How to get the null counts for each column in a table with 500 columns?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

My use case is to calculate the null counts for each column in a table(which is having 500 columns)..i cannot do manually because of this large number of columns..Can anyone please suggest me how to proceed on this...

Comment: Use a spreadsheet to construct the query.  But because RedShift is a columnar database, don't be surprised if the query takes a long time.

Comment: How many rows do you have?

Comment: almost 8million rows are there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any given column you can, of course, just run:

```
select count(1) from column_name where column_name is null
```

For 500 columns, though, you'll definitely want to programatically create the query. You have two options: which one will be faster will depend on how big your table is and how your columns are encoded.

Option 1: column-by-column method

If you run the following query (with `WHERE tablename='yourtable'` instead of 'users'), the output will itself be a query that you can run to get your answer.

```
SELECT 'select \'spacer\' AS column_name, 0 AS null_count ' union all
SELECT 'union all select \'' || "column" || '\', count(1) from ' || tablename || ' where ' || "column" || ' is null'
FROM pg_table_def
WHERE tablename = 'users'
AND NOT "notnull"
```

Option 2: row-by-row method

The output of this query will also give you the null counts (be sure to change both instances of `users` to your own table name!)

```
SELECT 'select' UNION ALL SELECT 'count(nvl2(' || "column" || ',null,1)) as ' || "column" || ', '
FROM pg_table_def
WHERE tablename = 'users'
AND   NOT "notnull"
UNION ALL
SELECT 'null as spacer from users '
```

This second option uses two odd features. First, `count(exp)` will count the number of instances for which `exp` is not null.

Second, and more confusing: the `nvl2(exp, val1, val2)` method will return val1 if exp is not null and to val2 if it is null. So `nvl2(exp,null,1)` is equivalent to `nullif(exp is not null)`. This means that `count(exp)` will count the non-null occurrences of exp while `count(nvl2(exp,null,1))` will count the null occurrences of exp.

Comment: Thanks for quick response Can you please give me a small example ?for the option-1 query

Comment: My editor (DataGrip) is pretty sure that it doesn't like the end of the first line in option one (SELECT ... union all), and redshift is returning an error "invalid syntax error at end of input. Is the whole thing on single query or is there something I'm missing in my understanding? The second part (SELECT .... "notnull") returns what I'm think I'm expecting.

Comment: Additionally, is the intent for this to be copy pasted from the output into the SQL editor? Or is there a way to use the execute command on the query to automatically use the output in another query?

Comment: Thank you. It works when I manually copy the output query into my sql editor and run. Is there any way to execute the output query without the copy and paste step?

Comment: why does this not work in Looker?